# В чем разница между каталогами /, /usr, /usr/local в Filesystem Hierarchy Standard?

Tags: linux, debian, файловая-система

В чем разница между каталогами /, /usr и /usr/local?

Почему одни пакеты должны устанавливаться в /bin, а другие в /usr/bin, третьи же в /usr/local/bin? ну и соответственно /etc -> /usr/local/etc и т.п.

Comment: Ну так почитайте стандарт. Даже википедия даёт начальную информацию https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: [и даже русская википедия даёт](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: и что там я прочитаю? "вторичная файловая система", "Третичная иерархия для локальных данных, специфичная для этого хоста". как понять, что вторично, а что первично? и что значит "специфичная для этого хоста", разве есть пакеты, которые на каждом хосте отличаются?
у меня fail2ban установился в /usr/local/bin, но ведь он не специфичен для этого хоста, он везде одинаковый

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук специфичен в понимании FHS, т.к. не принадлежит дистрибутиву (не связан с ним версионными/пакетными зависимостями), а установлен вами локально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### начнём с последнего, `/usr/local`.

когда вы «руками» собираете какие-нибудь программы, общепринятый префикс для их установки — `/usr/local`. блобы устанавливаются в `/usrl/local/bin`, конфигурационные файлы в `/usr/local/etc` и т.д. и т.п.

это помогает избежать конфликтов с теми файлами, которые входят в базовую систему и/или устанавливаются пакетным менеджером — в обоих случаях каталог `/usr/local` не используется.

#### теперь про `/usr` и `/`

каталог `/usr` может монтироваться по сети (когда-то в больших локальных сетях это было обычной практикой — для удобства администрирования и для экономии места). поэтому в случае сбоев и/или при работе в однопользовательском режиме (который как раз и актуален именно при починке после сбоев) содержимое каталога может быть недоступно. поэтому размещаются туда только файлы, которые не могут потребоваться для починки после сбоев.

соответственно, то, что может понадобиться для починки (и/или при работе в однопользовательском режиме), должно располагаться за пределами каталога `/usr`.

---

тут есть некоторая логическая неувязка: если `/usr` может использоваться совместно несколькими компьютерами локальной сети (логично, что при этом содержимое монтируется в режиме «только для чтения»), то как же насчёт `/usr/local`, который служит для локально собираемых программ?

вероятно, в случае совместного сетевого использования `/usr`, в `/usr/local` должна монтироваться отдельная локальная файловая система (или содержимое какого-нибудь локального каталога, с опцией `--bind` — см. `$ man 8 mount`)

Comment: спасибо за ответ. у меня локальной сети нет, ничего не монтируется. каждый хост отдельно существует. ну в общем вы мне помогли, выбирать /usr/local, если я вручную устанавливаю что-то руками

Comment: По поводу локальной сети и монтирования `/usr`. Речь идёт про то время, когда компьютеры были большими, а программы - маленькими. И каждый килобайт был на вес золота. Щас с огомными винтами\ссд нет проблем пихнуть себе гиг-другой бинарников, а во времена UNIX и терминалов - такая штука была очень кстати.

Comment: @donRumata, да и сейчас есть вполне современные системы, в которых идёт борьба за каждый килобайт. (Да, с Linux на борту при 32Mb / 64 Mb RAM)

Comment: @0andriy, ты про встраиваемые решения? И чё, там есть мало какого-нить eprom, но дофига сети с tftp\nfs?

Comment: @donRumata, так а ядру то же ж нужна память, или как по-твоему данные времени работы системы хранить? Во флешку что ли записывать?!

Comment: @donRumata Вот, смотри что автор https://lore.kernel.org/linux-gpio/20201019141008.871177-1-daniel@0x0f.com/ утверждает: *The machines this is used on generally only have 64 or 128MB of RAM so the kernel is usually built without modules and only the totally required stuff built in.* Письмо от октября сего года, на минуточку.

Comment: @donRumata, а твой пассаж про сетевые ФС ну вообще не в тему. Встраиваемые на то и встраиваемые, чтобы никаких сетевых ФС.

Comment: @0andriy, я не про "мало оперативы", я про "в 2к20м нет смысла подтягивать `/bin` по сети, а `/usr/local` хранить локально". P.S. В "stars" https://github.com/zhovner/OneFileLinux есть мой лайк.